# An equality from Representation Theory

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, finite-groups, summation

Studying Representation Theory of finite groups I've bumped in the following identity:

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(2i-1)!!(2n-2i+1)!!}{(2i-2)!!(2n-2i)!!}$$

My book suggests to prove it looking at the dimension of the representation of $S_n$ related to a particular partition of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Now my question: someone has other ideas to prove the above equality? 
In particular I'm looking for an elementary proof (by combinatorics or by analytical instruments).

Comment: By other ideas do you mean you want ideas not related to the book's suggestion? Or can we expand on the book's hint for a solution?

Comment: Ideas not related to the book suggestion. Right precisation, I edit the post immediately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$\frac{(2i-1)!!}{(2i-2)!!}=\frac{(2i-1)!}{4^{i-1}(i-1)!^2}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2i}\theta\,d\theta=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{2i}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx,$$
$$\frac{(2n-2i+1)!!}{(2n-2i)!!}=\frac{2}{\pi}(2n-2i+1)\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n-2i}\theta\,d\theta$$
hence:
$$\frac{(2i-1)!!}{(2i-2)!!}\cdot\frac{(2n-2i+1)!!}{(2n-2i)!!}=\frac{2}{\pi\cdot i! (n-i)!}\Gamma\left(i+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}+n-i\right)$$
and you identity follows from the generalized [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) 
with $m=\frac{1}{2}$ and $n=\frac{3}{2}$.